# Can you explain likelihood function in the equation?

Tags: estimation

In the paper [here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Iman_Tabatabaei_Ardekani/publication/283426265_A_Statistical_Inverse_Problem_Approach_to_Online_Secondary_Path_Modeling_in_Active_Noise_Control/links/563ae30f08ae405111a596dd.pdf), just before equation 12, authors introduce likelihood function $\pi(r|\theta)$. What does $\theta$ represent here ?. What is the intuitive explanation behind equation 12?

Answer (score 2):

To me, it looks like $\theta$ is just a throw-away "any variable". They might just as well have written $r(s|\cdot)$.

Equation 12 is just saying that because $r$ and $s$ are mutually independent, the distribution of the error $\rm\bf e$ does not change. Compare (12) with (10) rearranged to give an expression for $\rm\bf e$.

Comment: The $\theta$ seems to come out of no where. It was never mentioned before or after.

Comment: @SajilC.K. : Yes, $\theta$ is often used as the general "parameter vector".  As I say, it's just a throw-away remark.